# Use map object instead of params correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, testing, mapped-types

I want to use map object instead of calling checkOrder 3 times. How to use via Map instead of all params in this case? :

Admin.ts

```
class Admin{
  async checkTest(
    local: string,
    suburb: string,
    international: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    await checkOrder(local, "Declined");
    await checkOrder(suburb, "Declined");
    await checkOrder(international, "Declined");
    return;
  }
}
```

Test.ts

```
test("Test", async (t) => {
  await Admin.checkTest(
    "Local Place",
    "Suburb Place",
    "International Place"
  );
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you please clarify? What Map?

Comment: @Thomas I want to use map object instead of calling checkOrder 3 times .

Comment: Array can do the same thing, and with fixed order when calling checkOrder So why map?

Comment: @ABOS I just searching the best way. can you suggest your version, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

> @Thomas I want to use map object instead of calling checkOrder 3 times .

like this?

```
class Admin {
  async checkTest(map: Map<Place, Status>) {
    for (let [place, status] of map) {
      await checkOrder(place, status);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
test("Test", async (t) => {
  await Admin.checkTest(
    new Map([
      ["Local Place", "Declined"],
      ["Suburb Place", "Declined"],
      ["International Place", "Declined"],
    ])
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, something like this . But, i have an error : Cannot find name 'Place' and 'Status'

Comment: @Puzzle234 I took that 1:1 from your question. I assumed that would be the types for the key and value

Comment: @don't understand, do I need to add additional interface or what?

Comment: @Puzzle234 You literally wrote *"How to use via Map( **Map<Place, Status>** ) instead of all params"*. Where did you get these types from?

Comment: let's start again , okay, forget about<Place, Status> . How to use map object instead of calling checkOrder 3 times in my case?

Answer (score -1):

So, is it correct map using in my case ?

```
class Admin {
  async checkTest(map: Map<string, string>) {
    for (let [place, status] of map) {
      await checkOrder(place, status);
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
test("Test", async (t) => {
  await Admin.checkTest(
    new Map([
      ["Local Place", "Declined"],
      ["Suburb Place", "Declined"],
      ["International Place", "Declined"],
    ])
  );
});
```

Comment: Don't ask a question in your answer. Also this looks copied from the answer below